# Javascript variable & ajax ; with JsonForm. Using .jsonForm() with a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, variables

I'm using JsonForm: https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform/wiki#wiki-getting-started

I'm trying to load a form schema into $('form').Jsonfrom(), from an external .txt file,

attempting this by loading it into my .html file with ajax, putting it in a javascript variable , then calling $('form').Jsonfrom() with a click event .

Here is my code:

```
<script>    
#Load in .txt to javascript variable using ajax    
var stringData = $.ajax({
                    url: "schema.txt",
                    async: false
                 }).responseText;

#check that file is loaded correctly .- have check this works.
#alert(stringData);

#on clicking of a piece of text in a <p> wrapper call jsonForm function.    
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
       $('form').jsonForm(stringData   )
  });
});    

</script>
```

the error I'm getting in firebug is:

> "TypeError: this.formDesc.schema is undefined"

& my stack trace is this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2uiybo4/5

Think my problem may be in the way in loading in the .txt file with ajax.

however if I comment in: alert(stringData);  . . . the scheme for the for is displayed perfectly.

Like so: http://tinypic.com/r/2ynl9qh/5

Also there is no problem with the scheme, as i have tried putting it directly into in `$('form').Jsonfrom("here")` & it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this .

had to use a templating language (jinja2) instead of ajax, to get my form schema into my html document.. so that json form ( a jquery form builder) couple execute on a full html doc on the page loading .

Silly !

Hope this helps .